# Is $\frac{1}{\overline{z}}$ a Möbius transformation in the unit circle?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Basically, I have been studying about Möbius inversions recently and was a bit confused. I know that inversion in the unit circle can be represented as the map $z \rightarrow \frac{1}{\overline{z}}$, but I don't know if this is a Möbius transformation? And if it is not, is there a difference between this inversion and inversion in Möbius transformations?

Comment: The restriction of this map to the unit circle, $|z|=1$, is the identity, which is a Möbius transformation "on the unit circle".  But of course not "on the unit disk" as the answers explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z \mapsto 1/\overline{z}$ is the composition of a Möbius transformation and a reflection about the real axis.

Möbius transformations are all orientation-preserving, so they cannot model inversions directly. Instead, we have the Möbius transformation $z \mapsto \frac1z$, which is an inversion followed by a reflection (to restore orientation). This transformation keeps many of the properties of an inversion, such as mapping [clines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle) (circles or lines) to other clines.

All Möbius transformations can be expressed as compositions of translations, rotations, dilations, and the $z \mapsto \frac1z$ combo-inversion-reflection map.